# wrong proof for $K/k$ algebraic and every nonconstant polynomial in $k[x]$ splits in $K[x]$ implies $K$ is algebraically closed.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I'm reading the proof of Theorem 6.58 in Rotman's *Adavanced Modern Algebra*, Revised Printing of 1st edition.

> Theorem 6.58. Given a field $k$, there exists an algebraic closure $K$ of $k$.

After proved every nonconstant $f(x) \in k[x]$ splits in $K[x]$ and $K/k$ is algebraic. The author proves $K$ is algebraically closed by:

> Let $g(x) \in K[x]$ and let $E=K\left(\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_m\right)$ be a splitting field of $g(x)$ over $K$. We have a tower of fields $k \subseteq K \subseteq E$ in which $K / k$ and $E / K$ are algebraic extensions. By Lemma 6.56(i), $E / k$ is an algebraic extension. Hence, $p(x)=\operatorname{irr}\left(\alpha_1, k\right) \in k[x]$. By item (ii), $p(x)$ splits over $K$, so that $\\{\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_m\\} \subseteq K$; that is, $E \subset K$. Therefore, $g(x)$ splits in $K[x]$, and so $K$ is algebraically closed.

But the author then gives an errata removing this proof [here](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/%7Erotman/err.pdf), on the first paragraph and the third page.

Here Lemma 6.56(i) says if $E/K$ and $K/k$
are algebraic extensions, so is $E/k$, and item (ii) says every nonconstant $f(x) \in k[x]$ splits in $K[x]$.

I cannot see what's wrong with the quoted proof. It seems all things are fine. Altough $g(x)$ may be not irreducible, the quoted proof seems still holding on irreducible factors of $g(x)$.

Any helps? Thanks!

Comment: If “split” here means that *all* the roots of all polynomials defined over $k$ are in $K$, then I agree with you that the proof is correct. But maybe the statement for $K$ is that every polynomial in $k$ only has *one root* in $K$, then the proof doesn’t work.

Comment: @Aphelli Thanks! Yeah you are right. The author proves every polynomials over $k$ has a root in $K$, and then says that "it follows by induction on degree that the polynomial splits over $K$". The second argument using induction to prove the polynomial splits over $K$ is wrong.